Why do I get a binary solution even when I solve an LP problem with continuous variables?
I have a MILP in the following form
maximize $${\bf c}^T{\bf x}$$
subject to
$${\bf Ax}\le {\bf b}$$
Matrix ${\bf A}$ is a binary matrix, and very sparse.
It is a larger matrix with 300 rows and 1000 columns. Only 4000 elements are 1s while the remaining entries are 0.
${\bf x}$ is a binary decision variable.
The entries in ${\bf b}$ are all integers.
By relaxing ${\bf x}$, I transform this into an LP.
Luckily, when I solve this problem by making decision variables continuous, I get the optimized variable are already binary! I do not need to round them at all?
Why is this happening? I mean, why do I get a binary solution even when I try to solve an LP problem, not MILP? Of course, I prefer this solution, as my original problem is MILP.
Are any characteristics of matrix ${\bf A}$ helping this to happen, ie., to have a binary solution readily available?.

Totally unimodular (see added tag) constraint matrices have this property.  One common example is when the constraint matrix corresponds to a network flow problem, with one variable per arc and one constraint per node.
